# Problema de codificação diferente ao registrar dados via projeto PHP ou direto pelo MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, utf-8

Amigos, tudo bem?

Estou em aprendizado sobre com PHP e ao testar conexões com o MySQL percebi um problema curioso:

Se estou utilizando o phpMyAdmin e através dele insiro registros, com acentuação, em minha tabela a informação é exibida normalmente ao realizar um SELECT. Porém, ao exibir estes dados em meu projeto PHP os mesmos não apresentam os acentos e invés disso apresentam aqueles caracteres já bem conhecidos desta situação.

Por outro lado, se insiro os dados através do meu projeto em PHP a exibição ocorre normalmente com os acentos, mas ao puxar o SELECT dentro do phpMyAdmin o registro retorna com erro na codificação destes acentos.

Percebam que, em ambos os casos eu posso visualizar a informação com os caracteres acentuados e na mesma tela haverão registros com caracteres corrompidos, seja no meu projeto PHP ou através da interface do phpMyAdmin, tendo como o diferencial deles a interface pela qual o registro foi inserido.

Ao criar o banco de dados eu utilizei a seguinte sequencia de comandos:

`CREATE DATABASE nome_banco
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

Para as tabelas utilizei a seguinte sequencia de comandos:

`CREATE TABLE nome_tabela (
...
) DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;`

E, em meu projeto PHP, utilizo um arquivo template que leva no HTML:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
     <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />`

Alguém tem alguma dica do que pode estar havendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O "utf8" do MySQL não é bem UTF-8, pois suporta apenas 3 bytes por caractere, enquanto UTF-8 de verdade — que todo mundo usa, incluindo sua aplicação PHP — necessita de 4 bytes por caracter.

Essa é uma das prováveis causas de sua divergência.

Se a versão do seu MySQL for superior a 4.1, faça um teste utilizando `utf8mb4` no encoding do seu MySQL, que implementa a versão de 4 bytes do UTF-8.

```
CREATE DATABASE nome_banco
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
DEFAULT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE nome_tabela (
    ...
) DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4;
```

Esse [artigo (inglês)](https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434) explica direitinho todo o problema.

Comment: Juliano, obrigado pela ajuda.
Acho que o meu caso vai um pouco além. Na tabela não tenho problemas. A curiosidade é que se insiro os dados através da minha aplicação em PHP e visualizo na minha aplicação os acentos aparecem normais, mas se visualizo o mesmo registro dentro do banco através do phpMyAdmin, então os acentos não são reconhecidos. Da mesma maneira, se insiro o registro no banco através do phpMyAdmin e visualizo pelo próprio MyAdmin os acentos são exibidos normalmente, mas se tento verificar estes registro pela minha aplicação, então os acentos ficam corrompidos.